# Правописание Не или ни

Tags: орфография

Завтра ни одной машины не будет

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ни - не. Ни усиливает уже Не. Все правильно написано.